# Exporting in CSV file format for Python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to export some content in CsV format..but not able to do.

Below is the arbitrary idea that i am doing in python.

```
script , file = argv
emails = open(file,"r") #opens the file 
results = csv.writer(open("Results.txt" , "w")) #Creates a new file to show results.

resultsList = []

here is the complete data and all


for results in resulsList:
results.writeline(result)

results.close()
emails.close()
```

Now...i need to to save all the data which is stored in results.txt in CSV format.

Please provide your feedback for this.
thanks.

Comment: What are you writing to the file ? You could export all your data to the file using the similar method that you are using to write Results.txt. Just ensure that they each field are separated by commas (Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values for the basic rules of CSV formatting)

Comment: Don't use `results.close()`, use `with open("Results.txt","r") as inFile:`. Good practice ;) And what is the problem? You just read the data from the file, parse it, and dump into another file.

Comment: Looks like there's an indentation error after your `for` statement...

Comment: So what do the contents of results.txt look like and how are you reading them into your list object?

Answer (score 0):

You could use numpy [`genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) and [`savetxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html):

```
import numpy as np
np.savetxt('results.csv', np.genfromtxt(file,delimiter='',dtype=None),delimiter=',')
```

Note you must set the appropriate delimiter in `genfromtxt`